# How can my bluetooth headphones pause web content?

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, bluetooth

To my surprise I noticed that when I press pause on my Bose Q35C headphones they pause content playing in YouTube/SoundCloud on my MacBook Air 11" (2015). The media keys don't do that.

And I can't find this documented anywhere. What api are these websites using?

Comment: When you say "the media keys", do you mean the media keys on your keyboard, or the media keys on headphones (e.g. iPhone earbuds)?

Comment: I meant on the MacBook.